# Spring Boot response returns error allthough I got a 200 code

Tags: angular, spring-boot, httpresponse

On a HTTP POST I have to return a PDF document. I'm testing it with postman and it is working fine. When I try to use it in my Angular app I'm getting this error (posting as a picture for formatting reasons): 
[image]

So there is something wrong with my response but I can't find the error.

Where the response gets created:

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> compareWithLocal(CompareJob compareJob) {
        logger.info(compareJob);
        File leftFile = compareJob.getFile1();
        File rightFile = compareJob.getFile2();

        byte[] document = null;
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        try {
            final CompareResult result = new PdfComparator(leftFile, rightFile, new CompareResultWithPageOverflow()).compare();

            if (result.isEqual()) {
                logger.info("Compare job is: equal");
            } else {
                String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
                System.out.println("File written to: " + path);
                result.writeTo(path + "demo");
                compareJob.setCompareResultFile(new File(path + "demo.pdf"));
                // TODO: Delete temp
                logger.info("Compared file path: " + compareJob.getCompareResultFile());

                document = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(compareJob.getCompareResultFile());
                header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "pdf"));
                header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + compareJob.getCompareResultFile().getName());
                header.setContentLength(document.length);
                logger.info(document);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(document, header, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Where the method gets called to create the response:

```
@PostMapping("/pdfdiffLocal")
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> pdfDiffLocal(@RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1, @RequestParam("file2") MultipartFile file2) {
        logger.info("Received File 1: " + file1.getOriginalFilename() + ", File 2: " + file2.getOriginalFilename());
        PdfDiffCompare pdfDiffCompare = new PdfDiffCompare();
        File converted1 = convert(file1);
        logger.info("File 1: " + converted1);
        File converted2 = convert(file2);
        logger.info("File 2: " + converted2);

        CompareJob compareJob = new CompareJob(converted1, converted2);
        logger.info("Compare Job after convert. F1: " + compareJob.getFile1() + " F2: " + compareJob.getFile2());

        ResponseEntity<byte[]> returnComparison = pdfDiffCompare.compareWithLocal(compareJob);

        logger.info(returnComparison);
        return returnComparison;
    }
```

This is what I'm logging on the ResponseEntity:

```
<200 OK OK,[B@50fdfe86,{Content-Type=[application/pdf], Content-Disposition=[inline; filename=demo.pdf], Content-Length=[838078]}>
```

Angular part where I call the backend:

```
comparePdfDiff() {
        console.log('Submitted PDF Diff');
        let formModel = this.prepareSave();
        this.loading = true;
        console.log('Formmodel: ', formModel);
        this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/pdfdiffLocal', formModel)
            .subscribe((response: ApiResponseModel) => {
                console.log('response: ', response);
                this.router.navigate(['/pdfdiff']);

                let returnValue = JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log('parsed: ', returnValue);
                this.comparejobdataService.pdfFile.push(response.pdfFile);
            });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading = false;
        }, 10000);
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share the code you use to reach endpoint from angular?

Comment: Are you running angular on Apache? check what your web server is returning, it might be your web server not converting content type as expected. Check web server config.

Comment: I've added my angular code where I'm calling the backend. Thanks for your help!